# Strictly increasing function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $f$ be strictly increasing in $Ω\subset \mathbb{R}$. If $u,v$ in $C^2(Ω)$ hold that $Δu≤f(u)$, $Δv≥f(v)$ in $Ω$, and $u≥v$ $∂Ω$, prove that $u≥v$ in $Ω$.

This problem make sense? I think it should be $\mathbb{R}^2$  I don't know if $\Delta$ is the laplacian or if $\Delta u = u - u_0$.

Best Regards.

Comment: How would you define increasing in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I would split the function into its $x$ (and $y$) dependence and see if each one-dimensional function is strictly increasing.

Comment: Are you asking if it the problem statement makes sense in one dimension? If so, yes it does. In one dimension the laplacian is $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$. As for actually solving the problem itself, have you tried applying the maximum principle?

Comment: @Cocomos yeah. Thanks, solved it with that principle.

Comment: @Topologicalife Awesome! Not sure if it is allowed, but maybe you could post your answer below so others could learn from it.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. I didn't solve it.  My idea was enterely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions should be: ''Let $f$ be strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ and  $u,v$ in $C^2(Ω)$". Define
$$ s^+=\left\{\begin{array}{l}s\text{ if }s\ge0,\\0\text{ else.}\end{array}\right. $$
So $(v-u)^+|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ and $(v-u)^+\ge0$ in $\Omega$. From $Δu≤f(u)$, $Δv≥f(v)$, one has
$$ \Delta(u-v)\le f(u)-f(v).\tag{1} $$
Multiplying both sides of (1) by $(v-u)^+$ and integrating in $\Omega$, one has
$$ -\int_{\Omega}\Delta(v-u)(v-u)^+dx\le \int_{\Omega}(f(u)-f(v))(v-u)^+dx.\tag{2} $$
By integration by parts, one has
$$ \int_{\Omega}|\nabla(v-u)^+|^2dx\le \int_{\Omega}(f(u)-f(v))(v-u)^+dx.\tag{3} $$
Note that since $f(s)$ is increasing, one has $(f(u)-f(v))(v-u)^+\le0$ and hence
$$ \int_{\Omega}(f(u)-f(v))(v-u)^+dx\le 0.$$
Thus from (3) one hass
$$ \int_{\Omega}|\nabla(v-u)^+|^2dx\le0. $$
Namely $(v-u)^+=0$ in $\Omega$ or $v\le u$ in $\Omega$.